# Xamarin IOS Collection View Layout is misaligned at first render

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I'm new with xamarin and I have a really weird bug which is making me crazy. I have a Collection View inside a Tab  Item from xamarin tool kit.

The item template for the collection view consists on elements inside a Grid. Inside the template I have two grids which each one is visible depending on a boolean (IsStaticCheckList) which tells you if you have custom fields or normal fields.
I put my render function on the tap item command from the tab item (in that way I'm able to force the render each time the checklist item is tapped). The problem is that on IOS version the layout is not rendering well when I open the form for the first time but if we repeat the process it does it.

As an additional info:

- I'm using the MVVM pattern so I use commands for all actions inside my view model.
- The difference between custom and normal fields. In the UI is that you are able add as many normal fields in the list as you want and edit them. But if we are using custom fields you are not able to do those actions as you have a checklist template selected.
- This only happens on IOS version, Android version works as expected.

This issue only happens with normal fields (IsStatiChecklist = true) on ios version. I've been debbuging the code but nothing seems to be wrong. At the end the layout is working as expected at second time. But I'm not able to make it work the first time I open the form.

I attached some pictures for reference

- Here it is how it looks at first time (the 3 dot menu does not appear and the other fields neither because the content is using more space that it should) So all the elements are moved in some way to the right.

[Render issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRwmh.png)

- Here it is how it looks after I leave the tab and go again to my checklist tab

[Render Second time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3N7n3.png)

- Here is a screenshot of the other use case which is working correctly in all cases [custom fields screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkaZ5.png)

Here I attached my Item Template XAML Code

```
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:CheckListAnswerModel">
                                    <Frame>
                                        <Grid
                                            Margin="-10,-20,0,0"
                                            ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*,25,50,Auto"
                                            ColumnSpacing="3">

                                            <Grid
                                                Grid.Column="0"
                                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                                Padding="20"
                                                IsVisible="{Binding IsStaticCheckList, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:AddTaskViewModel}}}">

                                                <Label
                                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                                    IsEnabled="{Binding Complete, Converter={x:StaticResource InvertedBoolConverter}}"
                                                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                                    Text="{Binding Question}"
                                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                    IsVisible="{Binding ShowLabel}">

                                                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding EnableEditionCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:AddTaskViewModel}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                                                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>

                                                    <Label.Triggers>
                                                        <DataTrigger
                                                            Binding="{Binding Complete}"
                                                            TargetType="Label"
                                                            Value="true">
                                                            <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Strikethrough" />
                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                    </Label.Triggers>
                                                </Label>


                                                <Entry
                                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                                    IsEnabled="{Binding Complete, Converter={x:StaticResource InvertedBoolConverter}}"
                                                    IsVisible="{Binding ShowEntry}"
                                                    Placeholder="Click to add text"
                                                    ReturnCommand="{Binding CompleteAddCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:AddTaskViewModel}}}"
                                                    ReturnCommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                    Text="{Binding Question}"
                                                    TextColor="{x:StaticResource PrimaryColor}">

                                                    <Entry.Effects>
                                                        <effects:BorderlessEntryEffect />
                                                    </Entry.Effects>

                                                </Entry>

                                            </Grid>

                                            <ia:Checkbox
                                                Grid.Column="2"
                                                CheckColor="{x:StaticResource WhiteColor}"
                                                FillColor="{x:StaticResource DefaultButtonColor}"
                                                IsChecked="{Binding Complete}"
                                                IsVisible="{Binding Complete}"
                                                OutlineColor="{x:StaticResource DefaultButtonColor}"
                                                Shape="Circle" />

                                            <Image
                                                Grid.Column="3"
                                                IsVisible="{Binding HasTask}"
                                                Scale="0.5"
                                                Source="{x:Static res:Images.CreatedTaskIcon}" />

                                            <ImageButton
                                                Grid.Column="4"
                                                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                                Command="{Binding OpenMenuItemCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:AddTaskViewModel}}}"
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                Scale="2"
                                                Source="{x:Static res:Images.VerticalMoreIcon}"
                                                VerticalOptions="Center" />

                                        </Grid>
                                    </Frame>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

The Items Source for the collection view is called CheckList which has this definition:

```cs
private ObservableCollection<CheckListAnswerModel> _checklist;
public ObservableCollection<CheckListAnswerModel> Checklist
{
    get => _checklist;
    set
    {
        _checklist = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Checklist);
    }
}
```

Here is the funtion that tells the view model to add the corresponding items to the Checklist:

```cs
private async Task RenderElements()
{
    if (_checkListTemplateId > 0)
    {
        var checklistTemplate = _checkListTemplates.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == _checkListTemplateId);

        if (checklistTemplate != null)
        {
            CheckListTemplateText = checklistTemplate.Name;
            customFieldAnswer = String.Empty;
            _checkListTemplateId = checklistTemplate.Id;
            IsStaticCheckList = false;
            _checklistAnswerEntities = new List<CheckListAnswerEntity>();
            if (Id > 0 && loadAnswers) // taskId > 0
            {
                _checklistAnswerEntities = await _userTaskManager.GetChecklistAnswerByTaskId(Id);
            }
            if (_checklistAnswerEntities != null && _checklistAnswerEntities.Count() > 0)
            {
                await RenderCustomFields(checklistTemplate.ChecklistCustomFields, _checklistAnswerEntities);
            }
            else
            {
                await RenderCustomFields(checklistTemplate.ChecklistCustomFields);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            CheckListTemplateText = AppResources.Label_SelectTemplate;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (HasNormalItems)
        {
            IsStaticCheckList = true;
            Checklist = new ObservableCollection<CheckListAnswerModel>();
            foreach (var item in EditTaskParam.TaskListModel.CheckListItems)
            {
                CheckListAnswerModel model = new CheckListAnswerModel(new CheckListAnswerEntity { TaskId = item.TaskId, ChecklistCustomFieldId = item.Id, Question = item.ItemName });
                model.Complete = item.Complete;
                model.ShowEntry = false;
                model.ShowLabel = true;
                model.IsTextEntry = false;
                model.IsCustomDropdown = false;
                model.IsYesNoEntry = false;
                Checklist.Add(model);
            }
            SetCheckListLabel();
        }
        else
        {
            SetCheckListLabel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please annotate your screenshots to illustrate what the problem is.  At a casual glace I can't tell.

Comment: This is the kind of problem where a small GitHub repository with a minimally reproducible example might be helpful. Whenever there are rendering differences between iOS and Android, it's often hard to make out the problem just by seeing the code, in my experience.

Comment: That is a lot of xaml to read through. It would be best to delete all xaml that does not affect the problem. Presumably the problem still occurs with only a single item, and without all the `Swipe`-related xaml. You should confirm that, and update the question with just enough code to cause the symptom.

Comment: Yes I´ve also tried deleting all xmal code related to swipes. The error persists. I updated the xaml code with only the case that is failing (using a normal Label, not my custom one) and no swipe code.

Comment: Based on your code, I can't reproduce your problem. Could you please provide more code about the view model? From the code you provided, it is hard to know if you used Xamarin tool kit(Community Toolkit), can you tell me how you use it?

Comment: Hi everyone, I was able to solved my issue. The bug was cause by the xct tab view (not sure why exactly). But I refactored my code to use another tab plugin (Sharpnado.Tabs) and then the bug dissapear in all cases. Thanks for your comments